# JavaFX finds media file in JAR, but won't play it?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-2, executable-jar

My project plays audio files fine in Eclipse, but when I package to a JAR file, the audio files packaged in the JAR will not play.

What's odd is that JavaFX seems to find the file just fine.

I instantiate the player like this:

```
    myClass.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(
            myClass.getClass().getResource("/audio/file.wav").toString()));
```

My debug string looks like:

```
    System.out.println(mediaPlayer.getMedia().getDuration() + " "
                       mediaPlayer.getMedia().getSource())
```

In eclipse it works fine and shows the file URL:

```
358.049887 ms file:/home/username/path/to/project/bin/audio/file.wav
```

When running from the JAR it shows the JAR URL:

```
358.049887 ms jar:file:/home/username/path/to/project.jar!/audio/file.wav
```

So it must be locating the file, because it reports the duration correctly when running from the JAR, but it doesn't play, and no exceptions are thrown. I've also noted that the player never seems to get to the "READY" status.

I'm packaging a standalone JRE with my JAR file, but I'm using the same release of Java in both eclipse and the JAR packaging (1.8.0_92).

I note also that I'm using the same getClass().getResource() approach to load button icons that I package with the application, and that works fine in eclipse and from the JAR.

Comment: I don't have an answer for the question, but for a short sound like this you should consider an [`AudioClip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) instead of creating a `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Thanks! If I simply replace MediaPlayer with AudioClip, everything works as expected! Does this mean there must be a bug in MediaPlayer? (At least in the older version I'm using?)

Comment: I don't know... It seems like a bug. It's possible that the `MediaPlayer` allows some latency between starting to play, and actually physically rendering the media (including the sound), so that your short sound finishes before the media player is properly started up. That seems a bit unlikely though. But `AudioClip` is the intended way to produce this functionality anyway.

Comment: Hmmm... but only when loaded via a JAR? I mention that just because it plays fine when loaded (via the same method) in eclipse. Or when the program running from the jar loads it from the filesystem via a non-jar path. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, not sure. It would take longer to extract the media from a jar file than directly from the file system, so if there's a timing issue it's possible. But, I'd call this a bug. Functionality shouldn't depend on things like that. Anyway, seems like you have a way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or not; it seems like one.

However, the intended approach for playing short sounds like the one you have is to use an [`AudioClip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html), instead of a `MediaPlayer`. This is a much lighter-weight class and is suitable for very short sound files.

Comment: I had an issue with my Eclipse JAR file playing AudioClip sounds. Refreshing my resources folder in Package Explorer worked for me. Wanted to mention this here in case anyone else in the future runs into a similar issue.